# how to i change mouse pointer to hand signal and change the color of row while mouse go over a row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iterator

```
<logic:iterate name="studentDetails" id="student" indexId="index">
    <tr>
        <td><bean:write name="student" property="name" /></td>
        <td><bean:write name="student" property="age" /></td>
        <td><bean:write name="student" property="class" /></td>
        <td><bean:write name="student" property="mark" /></td>
        <td><bean:write name="student" property="result" /></td>
    </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

I want to display all the student details, and want to highlight the passed student details in diffrent color/set mouse pointer as hand signal while mouse go over the rows in result table.

How can i checked the student details is passed or not and how to set the highlighting color in table iterator?

Comment: Please add parsed `HTML`

Comment: This seems like something that could be easily done with CSS (e.g.: `tr:hover { cursor:pointer; background:#f0f0f0; }`) and let the browser handle it, instead of having some jQuery/JavaScript logic to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add onmouseover or onmouseout in

```
<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this,${student.result})>
```

Add script also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeBackgroundColor(row, result) { 
        if(result =="pass")
        {
            row.style.backgroundColor = 00FF33;
             $(row).css("cursor","pointer");
        }
        else
            row.style.backgroundColor = #FF0000 ;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as "hand signal" I assume you mean mouse cursor switched to a hand. This can be done by applying the style `cursor: pointer;`. To highlight the row, you can use the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Combining the two, to highlight each row red while hovering with your mouse:

```
tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Example below:

```css
tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Susie</td>
      <td>Snowflake</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```